# How to change param from outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to change lang value on `export const GetWeatherDetails = ( location ="Paris", lang= 'en')`, what would be the proper way to do it, it's an **Action.js** file so I need to get it done from **App.js** or another file in this case I got **Weather.js**

```
export const GetWeatherDetails = ( location ="Paris", lang= 'en') => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: GET_WEATHER.PENDING });
  axios
    .get(BASE_URL, {
      params: {
        q: location,
        lang: lang,
        units: "Metric",
        
      }
    })
    .then(response =>
      dispatch({ type: GET_WEATHER.SUCCESS, payload: response.data })
    )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.response, err);
      toast.error(err.response.data.message, {
        position: "bottom-center",
        autoClose: 2000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        draggable: false
      });
      dispatch({ type: GET_WEATHER.REJECTED, payload: err.response });
    });
};
```

Comment: `lang` is an argument to `GetWeatherDetails` function with its default value set to `en`. Wouldn't supplying the `lang` value whenever/ wherever you call `GetWeatherDetails` work?

Answer (score 0):

As @IronGeek pointed out, `lang` is the second argument to the `GetWeatherDeatils` function. It's predefined with the `"en"`, so that if you call `GetWeatherDetails` without the second argument, `"en"` is used. For example:

```
 GetWeatherDetails('Berlin')
```

If you want to pass in another value, just *call* `GetWeatherDetails` with other values:

```
 GetWeatherDetails('Berlin', 'de')
```

You can read more about default function arguments at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters